# How to get more than 21 images to appear using jFlickr Feed Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox, flickr

I am using the jFlickr Feed Plugin to display images from a tour we are having. Problem is that I am only getting 21 images to display.

the Plugin website can be seen here: http://www.gethifi.com/blog/a-jquery-flickr-feed-plugin

I also am using the [colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) callback feature where if an image is clicked on it opens in an overlay to view. I was hoping to find out how to get the descriptions to display along with the title.

Any help would do guys

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I was getting only 20 images from the request is there is a limitation to the numbers of request that can be made to Flickr.

Unless someone know a work around... until then I have no choice but to only show 20 at a time.